# GGplot geom_point - how to get inherit.aes = FALSE to properly work?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-point

I'm trying to plot a separate set of datapoints on an existing ggplot. The scenario is where one of my treatment means was thrown off by an anomalous replicate, so I was trying to show each replicate on the graph as well. However, I'm running into the "Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data" issue with geom_point, despite already specifying inherit.aes = FALSE.

See below reproducible sample.

```
#create dataset 
light <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3)
chlorophyll <- c(-50,20,30,5,10,15)
species <- c('grass','grass','grass','tree','tree','tree')
plot <- data.frame(light,chlorophyll,species)

#plot this information 
ggplot(plot, aes(x=light, y=chlorophyll,color=as.character(species))) +
  geom_point(size = 10, shape = "diamond") + 
  geom_line()+
  ggtitle('Chlorophyll') +
  theme_classic() +
  labs(color='Species') +
  xlab('Light') + ylab('Chlorophyll') 
#remove anomalous treatment
newplot <- filter(plot,light!=1  | species != 'grass')
#plot again
ggplot(newplot, aes(x=light, y=chlorophyll,color=as.character(species))) +
  geom_point(size = 10, shape = "diamond") + 
  geom_line()+
  ggtitle('Chlorophyll') +
  theme_classic() +
  labs(color='Species') +
  xlab('Light') + ylab('Chlorophyll') 
#produce sample replicates for anomalous treatment
anomalylight <- c(1,1,1)
anomalychlorophyll <- c(10,20,-180)
anomalyspecies <- c('grass','grass','grass')
anomaly <- data.frame(anomalylight,anomalychlorophyll,anomalyspecies)
#plot anomaly on with geom_point
ggplot(newplot, aes(x=light, y=chlorophyll,color=as.character(species))) +
  geom_point(size = 10, shape = "diamond") + 
  geom_line()+
  ggtitle('Chlorophyll') +
  theme_classic() +
  labs(color='Species') +
  xlab('Light') + ylab('Chlorophyll') +
  geom_point(data=anomaly,aes(x=light,y=chlorophyll),color='red',inherit.aes=FALSE)
```

This gives the aforementioned error; I don't understand why it is still inheriting the aesthetic of the first layer when I've already specified it not to.

Alternatively, I've seen people recommending to not specify aes in ggplot() so that the aesthetics don't get inherited, so I've tried (for the last code block)

```
#plot anomaly on with geom_point
ggplot() +
  geom_point(data=newplot, aes(x=light, y=chlorophyll,color=as.character(species)),size = 10, shape = "diamond") + 
  geom_line()+
  ggtitle('Chlorophyll') +
  theme_classic() +
  labs(color='Species') +
  xlab('Light') + ylab('Chlorophyll') +
  geom_point(data=anomaly,aes(x=light,y=chlorophyll),color='red',inherit.aes=FALSE)
```

but the same issue persists. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think this is just a typo. You want `aes(x = anomalylight, y = anomalychlorophyll)` in your last `geom_point()` call. Those are the names of the columns in your `anomaly` dataset. `light` and `chlorophyll` are vectors defined in the global environment, and longer than the number of rows in `anomaly`, hence the error.

Comment: _This_ --- defining vectors first and them dumping into a frame with the same name --- is likely the cause of so many problems in R. Yes it's convenient, but as you can see the ambiguity and sources of error are higher. I suggest following `<- data.frame(a, b, c)` with `rm(a, b, c)` so that the previous vector objects are no longer accidentally used. (I also suggest never naming an object the same as a function, such as `plot`, `data`, or `df`, since errors associated with this process can be more confusing than otherwise.)

Comment: Agree. You can of course also just define the vectors in the `data.frame()` call directly, eg `data.frame(a = 1:3, b = c("zip", "zap", "zop"))`.